# alphabetical order get first and last word

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get First and Last record from a sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485391/how-to-get-first-and-last-record-from-a-sql-query)

I have words sorted by alphabetical order in the mysql db. How can I get the first and last words for each letter of the alphabet.

so let's say there are the following words in the db:

air
airplane
awol
around

I want to concatenate the first and last words of the alphabet (so in this case air-around). I want to get the first and last word starting with a particular letter sorted by alphabet.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4899070/1177083

Comment: Your example doesn't match what you want to get done. In your example's case, it should be "air-awol".

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick and works on non sorted data as well, try

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(word),' - ',MAX(word))
FROM table
GROUP BY ASCII(LOWER(word))
```

where it basically fetches the alphabetically first and last instance of every letter and concats them. ASCII(word) just gets an ASCII arithmetic value for the leftmost letter of a word, so essentially it's grouping by each first letter(or number or symbol) of a word or sentence and outputs a nice 'encyclopaedia' like list.

Comment: Minor edit by changing grouping to LOWER(), this way the returned list does not return separate rows for lowercase and uppercase first letters.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select min(name)
from your_table
group by substring(name, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $str = "air airplane awol around";

    $exp = explode(' ', $str);

    $count = count($exp); // counting no. of items in array
    $count = $count--;     // reducing count by 1 because index starts from 0
    $first = $exp[0];     // storing first word
    $last = $exp[$count]; // storing last word

    echo $first." - ".$last;
```

Comment: +1 or just `$lastword = $exp[count($exp)-1];`

Comment: yeh that would do too..just wanted to make it simpler to understand

Comment: The asker doesn't have that as a string, those are database values . . . it looks like he should do a SQL query to get the first and last, with a WHERE + LIKE clause to limit the first letter, e.g. WHERE field LIKE 'A%'