# Is there any way to pluck first result from a query result pre-While loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

My site has a sizable table generated by a mysqli_query; the query includes a column 'messagetime':

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, 
"
  SELECT ......., messagetime
  FROM messages 
  ORDER by messagetime 
  DESC
"
);
```

I then generate the table (in php) with the help of a while loop:

```
echo "<table id='myTbl' class='newest' border='1'>";
echo "<th>Content</th> //etc.
echo "<tbody>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // Fill the table body here

}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Nothing earth-shaking. However, the site uses polling to refresh the table, and I need to store the `messagetime` of the first result of the query in the table, like this:

```
echo "<table id='myTbl' class='newest".$newestTime."' border='1'>";
```

Right now, to capture the first (newest) messagetime, I am tweaking my While loop to do this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     if ($i == 0) {
         echo "<table id='myTbl' class='newest".$row['messagetime']."' border='1'>";
         echo "<th>Content</th> //etc.
         echo "<tbody>";
     }

    // Fill the table here

     $i++;
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

However, this seems kind of hacky to me. Is there any way, without a subquery or union (since my query is actually the product of 2 joins, and is already expensive; this approach was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899042/how-to-select-first-and-last-data-row-from-a-mysql-result)), to simply pluck the first result from the query somehow, something like this?

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, 
"
  SELECT ......., messagetime, **first_messagetime_result AS newest_time**
  FROM messages 
  ORDER by messagetime 
  DESC
"
);
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` can be called before the while loop to fetch the first record; do what you want with it; then just use a `do {...} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));` to process the results

Comment: OK...so a second while loop needs to be invoked. I have used mysqli_data_seek() before to reset the while loop...I guess I can use this here too

Comment: Thanks Mark...I appreciate the response

Comment: Why a second while loop?

Comment: Oh..I misunderstood.....$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) doesn't need a while...my bad.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
    echo "<table id='myTbl' class='newest".$row['messagetime']."' border='1'>";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>Content</th>"; //etc.
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    do {
        // Fill the table here
    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but it sounds like the answer to doing this within the SELECT query is 'no'. Regardless, thanks for the insight

Comment: That's because there's no need to do it within the select query

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the first or other rows if you like before running it through the shile loop.   The while loop will start with any rows that have not been called already.  It's easy to forget that the while only exists to loop through the rows until it is done.   We always could call a row from the query, but we institute the while to specifically do *more*.

All you need to do is this

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

then you can do something like this to store the messagetime in a variable

```
$messagetime = $row;
```

and then you can use this variable how you like

After this instance the first row of your query has id of 1, when running the below, it will start with 2.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... }
```