# MySQL - Retrieve rows corresponding to timestamps

Tags: mysql

I am looking to retrieve db rows corresponding to the timestamps of 7am "yesterday" and 7am "today".  I was already assisted with the code:

```
SELECT * FROM `monthly`
WHERE LogDateTime - INTERVAL 7 hour BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day AND CURDATE() or LogDateTime BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day + INTERVAL 7 hour AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 hour ORDER BY `LogDateTime`  DESC
```

This gives me every minutes from 7am to 7am.  However, my ultimate goal is to get just the first and last rows so that I can compare data against each.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select first and last data row from a mysql result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899042/how-to-select-first-and-last-data-row-from-a-mysql-result)

Comment: Kind of?  It seems like this would just end up being a series of nested select statements.  Which I am hesitant to use as this table is over 20 millions rows

Comment: The heavy lifting is done with two queries: one to get the first and one to get the last. You're already doing one query, so if your tables are indexed properly, doing a second should result in negligible overhead.